# Deleting an element from a vector of object pointers allocated on the stack

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

I have a vector of Object pointers. I want to be able to delete those objects and free the memory taken up by those objects.

What I have currently is this:

This is the vector that contains the object pointers:

```
std::vector<Ball*> List;
```

This is the function that deletes the element in the vector and frees the memory:

```
void BallManager::DeleteBall(int id) 
{
    List[id]->~Ball(); //Not sure if this is needed
    delete List[id];
    List[id] = NULL;
    List.erase(List.begin()+id);
}
```

My question is do I need to also call the destructor for the object or is that taken care of by delete?

Comment: I highly recommend a vector of smart pointers instead. You won't need to worry about managing the pointer's memory if you do; simply calling `erase` would deallocate the memory and everything as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete pointer element, `delete` will call object destructor. No need to call 
`List[id]->~Ball()` also no need to set pointer to NULL as you are going to erase the element anyway.

```
std::vector<Ball*> List;

void BallManager::DeleteBall(int id) 
{
    if (id < List.size())   // should check id is still in range
    {  
      delete List[id];
      List.erase(List.begin()+id);
    }
}
```

Strongly recommand you use smart pointer as Chris mentioned, then you don't need to worry about deleting object pointer when you delete element from STL container, demo as below:

```
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ball> > List;
  void BallManager::DeleteBall(int id) 
  {
     if (id < List.size())   // should check id is still in range
     {  
        List.erase(List.begin()+id);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, calling delete (as opposed to dealloc) automatically calls the destructor.

After deleting the element, there is no need to set it to null either, you can just erase it.

```
void BallManager::DeleteBall(int id) 
{
    delete List[id];
    List.erase(List.begin()+id);
}
```

new automatically calls the constructor, the corresponding delete automatically calls the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never have to explicitly call destructors.  They are called through the deallocation process -- delete in the case of dynamically allocated objects.

See [Destructors FAQ](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=370) about halfway down for more detail.